# MQ135 gives weird error after running the code

Tags: python

Press CTRL+C to abort.
Calibrating...
Calibration is done...

Ro=0.000000 kohm

Abort by user

```py
from mq import *
import sys, time

try:
    print("Press CTRL+C to abort.")

    mq = MQ();
    while True:
        perc = mq.MQPercentage()
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write("\033[K")
        sys.stdout.write("LPG: %g ppm, CO: %g ppm, Smoke: %g ppm" %
           (perc["GAS_LPG"], perc["CO"], perc["SMOKE"]))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)

except:
    print("\nAbort by user")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error is masked by the use of the try/except catching all exceptions.

Replace the `except:` with `except KeyboardInterrupt:`

That will result in a stack trace showing the actual error.

It's preferable not to use wild-card exceptions for this precise reason.